# Is $\int x\,dx \cdot x=\int x^2 \,dx$ or $\int x\,dx \cdot x=(\int x \, dx)\cdot x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

Is $\int x\,dx \cdot x=\int x^2 \,dx$ or $\int x\, dx \cdot x=(\int x \,dx)\cdot x$?

Edit: My integrals looks like this:
\begin{align}
& \int_0^t e^{-\xi(t-t^\prime)} \, d t^\prime \int_0^t e^{-\xi(t-t^{\prime \prime})} \frac{2 C}{m^2} \delta(t^{\prime}-t^{\prime \prime}) \, dt^{\prime \prime} \\[6pt]
= {} &\int_0^t e^{-\xi(t-t^\prime)} \, d t^\prime\left(e^{-\xi(t-t^\prime)} \frac{2 C}{m^{2}} \Theta(\mathrm{t}-\mathrm{t}^\prime)\right)
\end{align}
And I am not sure if the term in the parenthesis on the last line should be included in the integral.

Comment: In the case you are describing, it should be $x\left(\int xdx \right)$.

Comment: @Tavish do you mind explaining why?

Comment: Two integrals multiplied by each other. One of them results in a factor of $x$. Clearly, that factor must stay outside of the other integral. @CSquared

Comment: Your posted question [which is frankly somewhat problematic] involves indefinite integrals - but you say you are actually interested in a double integral with limits. Perhaps we would have an easier time helping you if you gave us the integral and wrote down the steps that you're interested in understanding

Comment: @peterag, I have added the integrals I am trying to evaluate.

Comment: And the first-described scenario was incorrect: the second term becomes a function of the variable of the first integral due to the Dirac-delta.

Comment: Here's my best answer: nobody should ever write $\int x\,dx \cdot x$, precisely because its meaning is ambiguous.

Comment: A lot of physicists and engineers write (particularly in the context of iterated integrals) $\int dx\,f(x)$ for $\int f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends always on the context. The $dx$ part does not need to be at the end of the integral, for example, in quantum mechanics you see a lot of integrals written like:

$$\langle \psi| \hat V |\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 |B|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx x^4 e^{-2 \alpha x^2}$$

and in this case, the integrand is $x^4 e^{-2 \alpha x^2}$. I think that they do this in integrals with large integrands so it's more visible and to make stand out what variable you are integrating over. So if $\int x dx x$ is $\int x^2 dx$ or  $x\cdot \int x dx$ always depends on the context of what you are doing and of what you are working with.